# How to return sender from Jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I use Jquery Autocomplete in my mvc3 application. I have a lot of textbox, and i try to do it smart :)
I need to return autocomplete field property  to controler. like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".AutoC[id]").autocomplete('@Url.Action("Liczba_wejsc", "Home")', { minChars: 1, selectFirst: true, extraParams: { "ID": $(this).attr('id')} });
});
</script> 
     <div class="editor-field">
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.some_prop)
 <br/>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.some_prop, new {
 id = "some_id", @class = "AutoC" })
    </div>
```

But allways i get null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i get it :

```
     </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".AutoC").each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).autocomplete('@Url.Action("Liczba_wejsc", "Home")', { minChars: 1, selectFirst: true, extraParams: { "ID": id} });
    });
});
    </script>
```